# Link taking style of a diffrent link

Tags: html, css

The Logo is white when it's supposed to be black idk why.
[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W50R1.png)

This is for a school project and I only really know the basics. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: rgb(248, 119, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(248, 119, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 83, 125, 1) 100%);
}

header {
  width: 97%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

header a:link,
a:visited {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

header nav ul li a:link,
a:visited {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

main {
  width: 97%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

footer ul li a:link,
a:visited {
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#">PhoneDirect</a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="what-to-buy.html">What to Buy</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <section>

  </section>
</main>

<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="what-to-buy.html">What to Buy</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

..............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Try providing a [mcve] (emphasis on **minimal**) and don't pad your question with garbage.

Comment: @Andrei , see Guy Incognito jsfiddle . Your code works fine . I also tried your code given, couldn't reproduce the issue you are mentioning.

Comment: @AndreiSaliba that's not exactly how to fix it - look at my answer for what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are not being specific with your styles in your `header` and `footer`.

If you look at your code, you have:

```
header a:link,
a:visited {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Then you have:

```
footer ul li a:link,
a:visited {
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

You are duplicating `a:visited` but not making it specific to the parent element. The comma does not inherit the parent element. And since CSS cascades and will style based on the last style it finds for an element, `a:visited` will always be white, not matter where the `a` tag appears.

To fix, change the `:visited` state selectors for the `header` and `footer`:

```
header a:link,
header a:visited {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Then you have:

```
footer ul li a:link,
footer a:visited {
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Edit:
You should also edit this to include `header`:

```
header nav ul li a:link,
header a:visited {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```